# xdg-open: no method available for opening ./directory

Tags: python, linux, unix, xdgutils

I try to open a directory using `xdg-open` in Ubuntu. It works if I run `xdg-open ./dir` in terminal.

I have a Flask web app that opens directories using `xdg-open` in some situations. When I start the app from terminal in development mode (By running `$ flask run` ) it works and opens all directories without any problems. But when i start it in production mode using Nginx & Gunicorn it returns:

```
xdg-open: no method available for opening ./test
```

The result is exactly same as the situation that I run xdg-open in non-graphical terminal(`alt+ctrl+f1`)

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution
Just I must set the `$DISPLAY` env variable to `:0` and then run the command.

s.th like this:

```
env = dict(os.environ)
env['DISPLAY'] = ":0"
subprocess.Popen('xdg-open ./some_folder',env=env,shell=True)
```